# Android Studio error "Internal error when trying to read zip file"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i'm a beginner in android studio (first time). I have this problem after i created empty activity then run with real device (mobile phone).

I hope some one can help me. Thank you.

**More information**

- My device run on android 5.1 and connect with usb
- Android studio v. 3.0.1
- ่JDK v. 9.0.4
- JRE v. 9.0.4
- Original code (empty project template)

I got the following message in the console.

> Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error when trying to read zip file 'C:\Users\Jimmy.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-core-ui-26.1.0.aar\3ac945728978df452e7f8cdd66ea71d9\jars\classes.jar'.
>
> Error:com.google.common.base.VerifyException
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error when trying to read zip file 'C:\Users\Jimmy.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-core-ui-26.1.0.aar\3ac945728978df452e7f8cdd66ea71d9\jars\classes.jar'.

[Attached Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTV2B.jpg)

Comment: I hope I can't bump this question, This is so annoying and random error.